# Compare 2 lists with better performance possible?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, foreach, uwp

I have 2 lists. One is a list of all files in a folder and the other is a list from a database. I have to compare those lists and I wonder if there is a better way to do it because I think the performance suffers from it. here are a few ways I did:

```
for(int i=0; i < docListFallback.Count; i++ )
{
    if (docListFallback[i].id == metadataItem.UniqueID.ToString())
    {
        if (docListFallback[i].modifiedDate < metadataItem.Geaendert)
        {
            isDocumentMissing = true;
            downloadFile = isDocumentMissing;
        }
        docListFallback.Remove(docListFallback[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

and this

```
for (int i = 0; i < docListModDate.Count; i++)
{
    if (docListModDate[i].id == metadataItem.UniqueID.ToString())
    {
        if (docListModDate[i].modifiedDate != metadataItem.Geaendert)
        {
           await _spManager.fileStorage.modifyDate(metadataItem.Geaendert, docListModDate[i].id);
        }
        docListModDate.Remove(docListModDate[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

and this

```
for(int i = 0; i < cleanupDocList.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < existingDocuments.Count; j++)
    {
        if(cleanupDocList[i].id == existingDocuments[j].UniqueID.ToString())
        {
            addToDelList = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            addToDelList = true;
        }
    }
    if(addToDelList)
    {
        toDelete.Add(cleanupDocList[i].filename);
    }
}

foreach(string fileToDelete in toDelete)
{
    await _spManager.fileStorage.DeleteFileAsync(fileToDelete);
}
```

Comment: Having a sorted list opens up a whole lot of optimization options.

Comment: What do you need as an output, a boolean value indicating lists are equal or lists of matching items only?

Comment: First question you should ask yourself is "how fast does it have to be?" and the second is "how fast is it?" Maybe you don't need to change anything at all (although @Martin's answer also makes your code easier to read, so is overall goodness).

Answer (score 3):

The performance problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cleanupDocList.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < existingDocuments.Count; j++)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

What is happening here is for each file in `cleanupDocList` you are enumerating all files in `existingDocuments`. This means if there is N files in both lists the time complexity is `O(N^2)`, which is not optimal.

In this case you can observe the only thing you are interested in is the `UniqueID`, so what you can do is to first build a `HashSet<string>` of all the ids in the `existingDocuments` list and then just check if the item exists in the hashset. This is much faster, as `HashSet<>` is implemented as a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which has constant average time complexity for lookup (`O(1)`), which means we overall got to `O(N*1)=O(N)` time complexity, which is significant, especially as `N` grows.

The code would look like this:

```
var existingIds = new HashSet<string>(
        existingDocuments.Select(doc => doc.UniqueID.ToString()));

for(int i = 0; i < cleanupDocList.Count; i++)
{
    if (existingIds.Contains(cleanupDocList[i].id))
    { 
        toDelete.Add(cleanupDocList[i].filename);
    }
}

foreach(string fileToDelete in toDelete)
{
    await _spManager.fileStorage.DeleteFileAsync(fileToDelete);
}
```

The great thing is that this approach not only improved performance, but greatly simplified the code at the same time. Let's call that a win-win :-) !

Answer (score 2):

I would use Linq's `Except()` to do this, to get a two-way comparison to find all the items that are in list1 but not list2, and vice-versa.

Here's an example just using lists of strings. This also shows how to find items in both lists:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>{"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"};

            var inList1ButNotList2 = list1.Except(list2);
            var inList2ButNotList1 = list2.Except(list1);
            var inBothLists        = list1.Intersect(list2);

            Console.WriteLine("In list1 but not list2 = " + string.Join(", ", inList1ButNotList2));
            Console.WriteLine("In list2 but not list1 = " + string.Join(", ", inList2ButNotList1));
            Console.WriteLine("In both lists          = " + string.Join(", ", inBothLists));
        }
    }
}
```

To use this approach for your problem, you'd need to have the two collections of items of the same type to compare, and a comparison method. In the code above, I'm just using the default string equality comparer, but you can create your own equality comparer, like so:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> // Instead of string, put your own type.
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x, y); // You'd implement your own comparison here.
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

which you can pass to the `Except()` methods:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>{"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"};

        var comparer = new MyComparer();

        var inList1ButNotList2 = list1.Except(list2,    comparer);
        var inList2ButNotList1 = list2.Except(list1,    comparer);
        var inBothLists        = list1.Intersect(list2, comparer);

        Console.WriteLine("In list1 but not list2 = " + string.Join(", ", inList1ButNotList2));
        Console.WriteLine("In list2 but not list1 = " + string.Join(", ", inList2ButNotList1));
        Console.WriteLine("In both lists          = " + string.Join(", ", inBothLists));
    }
}
```